# Comparison and Apply sorting on XBRL file with the help of XSLT any version 1 or 2.

Tags: xml, xslt, comparison, xbrl

My problem is i have 2 xml(xbrl) file which is XBRLfiles and file1 is tested file and file2 is generated by some tool.Both are same in data but few things are changes like Context(ID),unit(ID) and concept(name & ID).
Here are those file

*******  File1(Tested file or you can say BASE file for comparison)******

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href = "D:/Devang Barot/XSLT/Compare/sorting.xsl"?>
<!-- Copyright 2007 XBRL International. All Rights Reserved. -->
<xbrl 
xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" 
xmlns:concept="http://xbrl.org/formula/conformance/example" 
xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217">

  <link:schemaRef 
    xlink:type="simple" 
    xlink:href="12030-concept-tests.xsd"/>

  <link:linkbaseRef 
    xlink:type="simple" 
    xlink:arcrole="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink/properties/linkbase" 
    xlink:href="12030-dynamic-concept-formula.xml"/>

  <context id="c1">
    <entity>
      <identifier scheme="http://xbrl.org/entity/identification/scheme">AAA001</identifier>
    </entity>
    <period>
      <instant>2007-01-01</instant>
    </period>
  </context>

  <context id="c2">
    <entity>
      <identifier scheme="http://xbrl.org/entity/identification/scheme">BBB002</identifier>
    </entity>
    <period>
      <instant>2007-02-02</instant>
    </period>
  </context>

  <context id="c3">
    <entity>
      <identifier scheme="http://xbrl.org/entity/identification/scheme">CCC003</identifier>
    </entity>
    <period>
      <instant>2007-03-03</instant>
    </period>
  </context>

  <context id="c4">
    <entity>
      <identifier scheme="http://xbrl.org/entity/identification/scheme">DDD004</identifier>
    </entity>
    <period>
      <instant>2007-04-04</instant>
    </period>
  </context>

  <unit id="u1">
    <measure>iso4217:JPY</measure>
  </unit>

  <unit id="u2">
    <measure>iso4217:KPW</measure>
  </unit>

  <unit id="u3">
    <measure>iso4217:THB</measure>
  </unit>

  <unit id="u4">
    <measure>iso4217:TOP</measure>
  </unit>

  <!-- note that the concepts are reversed by the qname expression -->
  <concept:m4 contextRef="c1" unitRef="u1" precision="0">11000</concept:m4>
  <concept:m3 contextRef="c2" unitRef="u2" precision="0">2200</concept:m3>
  <concept:m2 contextRef="c3" unitRef="u3" precision="0">330</concept:m2>
  <concept:m1 contextRef="c4" unitRef="u4" precision="0">44</concept:m1>

</xbrl>
```

****File 2(Generated from some tool)******

```
<xbrl xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:eg="http://xbrl.org/formula/conformance/example" xmlns:concept="http://xbrl.org/formula/conformance/example" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217">
<link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="12030-concept-tests.xsd"/>
<link:linkbaseRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:arcrole="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink/properties/linkbase" xlink:href="12030-dynamic-concept-formula.xml" /> 
<context id="context_0">
<entity>
<identifier scheme="http://xbrl.org/entity/identification/scheme">AAA001</identifier>
</entity>
<period>
<instant>2007-01-01</instant>
</period>
</context>
<unit id="unit_0">
<measure>iso4217:JPY</measure>
</unit>
<eg:m4 contextRef="context_0" unitRef="unit_0" precision="0">11000.0</eg:m4>

<context id="context_1">
<entity>
<identifier scheme="http://xbrl.org/entity/identification/scheme">BBB002</identifier>
</entity>
<period>
<instant>2007-02-02</instant>
</period>
</context>
<unit id="unit_1">
<measure>iso4217:KPW</measure>
</unit>
<eg:m3 contextRef="context_1" unitRef="unit_1" precision="0">2200.0</eg:m3>

<context id="context_2">
<entity>
<identifier scheme="http://xbrl.org/entity/identification/scheme">CCC003</identifier>
</entity>
<period>
<instant>2007-03-03</instant>
</period>
</context>
<unit id="unit_2">
<measure>iso4217:THB</measure>
</unit>
<eg:m2 contextRef="context_2" unitRef="unit_2" precision="0">330.0</eg:m2>

<context id="context_3">
<entity>
<identifier scheme="http://xbrl.org/entity/identification/scheme">DDD004</identifier>
</entity>
<period>
<instant>2007-04-04</instant>
</period>
</context>
<unit id="unit_3">
<measure>iso4217:TOP</measure>
</unit>
<eg:m1 contextRef="context_3" unitRef="unit_3" precision="0">44.0</eg:m1>

</xbrl>
```

if any one is able to compare this and we want result only in TRUE and FALSE..

i have applied the logic of 
functx:index-of-node
functx:deep-equal
functx:Sequence-deep-equal
functx:destinct-deep

but not able to find it..
any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two XBRL instances through their low-level XML syntax is more involved than a deep equal. XBRL has a data model of its own, and comparisons must be done with respect to this data model (ideally with an XBRL processor, see final comments).

On the XML-syntactic level, the exact criteria for comparing facts (same context, same unit, same value, etc) are specified [here in the specification](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html#_4.10).

No deep equal should be needed except in the (very) specific (and not advised) case of typed dimensions using complex types, but this is not the case here. One needs to test that the facts are in bijection to each other, and test, for a candidate pair of facts:

- the concept names (including namespace)
- the units (the unit IDs are only used to resolve the corresponding unit element on both sides), also including namespace (the `iso4217` prefix is commonly used for currencies, but one never knows).
- the context (resolved with the context IDs), that is, entity scheme and ID as well as period (ideally with the semantics of XML Schema `date`/`dateTime` comparison in the value space). No dimensions are involved here, which makes the comparison simpler.

as well as, for a pair of facts that passes the above comparison:

- the value (also ideally with the semantics of the concept type from the taxonomy)
- the precision/decimals

XPath/XQuery/XSLT (with functx if needed) is probably a good approach, but it will be a complex query. In general, this is probably feasible with normal navigation, filtering predicates to match IDs, value comparisons, quantifiers, casts (to date, dateTime), QName comparison, etc.

Note that:

1. The above comparison makes sense if the taxonomies used are the same, which seems to be the case here. Otherwise, there is still the risk that even if the data matches, the metadata may differ.
2. The order of facts is irrelevant to XBRL, but sorting according to some criteria (such as concept names) is a way to go from quadratic complexity to O(nlog(n)). With the above documents, it will not make a difference, even though concept names in this case uniquely identify facts and are a good way to start designing the bijection.
3. XBRL processors take care of all the machinery of resolving the XML syntax of an instance to lists of facts with their associated characteristics, and are the best way to process XBRL documents. Comparing a tabular list of facts is much easier to do than the above. Ideally, only developers of XBRL products should have to process XBRL at the level of XML. XBRL users should not have to look at the XML syntax or write XPath against it.

   In the present case, it is straightforward because the documents are rather simple, and do not involve advanced features, but in general, if you attempt this, you will actually end up re-programming an XBRL processor from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform SEMANTIC xbrl comparison.

Under SEMANTIC xbrl comparison, the attributes that belongs to underlaying specifications (such as the ids, idrefs, xlink:label, xlink:to, xlink:from and even xlink:href) are not compared using their text representations but the referenced objects are compared using the already defined comparison mechanism in section 4.10 of the XBRL 2.1 specification

See: http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html#_4.10

We have implemented an XBRL Semantic comparator that is available on our web site. You can download the Java source code form this link:

http://www.reportingstandard.org/samples.zip

On that file there is this java class com.ihr.xbrl.sample.LaunchIXBRLv11ConformanceSuiteXHTML and on that class there is a public static Diff makeXBRLDiff(URL,URL) method that generates a difference report by searching at semantically equivalent nodes on the target file.